# Accessible "Go Back" button in Remix / React Router

Tags: accessibility, react-router-dom, remix.run

I have a "Go Back" button in Remix / React Router v6 like this:

```
import { useNavigate } from '@remix-run/react'

const navigate = useNavigate()
const goBack = () => navigate(-1)

<button onClick={goBack}>Go Back</button>
```

How can I make it accessible?

I tried to give the button a `role="link"`, but I don't know if that makes it WCAG complaint.

**Note:** `<Link to=".." />` is NOT what I want because you can get navigated from different parts of the app to my page, not only from the current path.

Comment: What exactly isn't accessible? It's a `button` element so it will have the correct accessibility role by default, will be interactable and focusable, and since it has clearly discernible text I don't think any aria-label is needed, etc. Is there something more specific you need? Have you run any accessibility audits against this specific code?

Comment: @DrewReese I'm unsure. I'm not good at accessibility, though I take it seriously. Its behaving different than an `anchor` tag. When I try my app with a screenreader, it says different things about the anchor tag than about this button, which is why I think it might be confusing to screen reader users, hence the question 

Comment: Links and buttons aren't the same type of element, so I wouldn't be surprised they are read differently via a screen reader. As long as nothing is flagged during an audit from an HTML structural standpoint, i.e. it is valid HTML and basic accessibility concerns are addressed, then I think the rest is more of a UX "thing". For example, the button simply states "go back".... but is it clear to a non-visual person the intent is to "navigate back a page"? Or if you can inform a user what exactly they are going back to, so it's overtly clear. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

A button that says "Go Back" and then does that... is fine. Sure, a button should do something on a page, and a link should take you to another page, but people will figure out what you're doing from context. Nothing about this seems inaccessible.

If you still want to use a link, you can always do

```
<a href="#" onClick={goBack}>Go Back</a>
```

and that should do the same thing. I'd test with a keyboard and with a screen reader to confirm, as always, of course.